# Using paper-icon-button as input button to submit a form

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying to use paper-icon-button as input button to submit a form.

```
<form method="POST" action="self">
   <paper-icon-button icon="star" extends="input" name="favourite" noscript></paper-icon-button>
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="1"/>                 
   <input type="hidden" is="favourite">
</form>
```

This doesn't seem to be submitting the form.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to also resolve field validation issues "required",

The best would be to use this property :

```
function submitForm(event) {
    Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
}
```

And not to forget the attribute "is" in the < form > tag :

```
<form is="iron-form" method="POST" action="self">
```

More information : [iron-form](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this work around:

```
<button type="submit">
  <iron-icon icon="star"></iron-icon>
</button>
```

Dont forget to import "iron-icon":

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
```

Also dont forget to strip the button default style:

```
button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance:none;
    border: 0;
}
```

Or as @Ben Thomas suggested, do this:

```
<form method="POST" action="self" id="the-form">
   <paper-icon-button icon="star" extends="input" name="favourite" raised onclick="submitForm()"></paper-icon-button>
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="1"/>                 
   <input type="hidden" is="favourite">
</form>

function submitForm() {
  document.getElementById('the-form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `paper-icon-button` is not a `button` or `input` of type `submit` and will therefore not submit the form. What you can do is add a click event to the button which calls a function which submits the form.